# Store DBnull in database for date column that accepts null

Tags: c#

I have a `DateTime` value that I will like to save to the database. The column allows null 
in the database. When I try to run the code below I get this error message.

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between system.dbnull and system.datetime

How can I store null or empty value for a date column?

```
public class ExcelData
{
  public DateTime? DateValue1 { get; set; }
}

DateValue1 = col28Value == null ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(col28Value)
```

Comment: you dont need to set DbNull to parameter.Value, just set parameter.Value = null that should be enough

Comment: How? can you provide some code please?

Comment: he means instead of DbNull.Value, use null

Comment: What type is `col28Value`?

Comment: If the column is nullable on the db DateValue1 = null should do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's telling you that you can't declare a `Nullable<DateTime>` and assign it a `DBNull.Value` which is not the same as `null`

Your code should simply be:

```
DateValue1 = col28Value ==null? (DateTime?)null: Convert.ToDateTime(col28Value)
```

Comment: Yes; this is exactly what I was describing.

Comment: @SLaks: Ah yes, the whole "C# can't look at the output type when resolving types" annoyance.

Comment: Probably how I'd wind up doing it, but wow so ugly...  Almost better to stick with if/else in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The conditional operator requires that one of its types be convertible to the other.
It will not try to find the closest common base type.

Since `DBNull` and `DateTime` have nothing in common, it fails.

You need to cast either side to `object`.

---

However, that won't work either.
`DBNull.Value` is a special object used for certain APIs in `System.Data`.
It has nothing to do with nullable types.

Instead, you need use `null` itself.
Since `null` is not convertible to `DateTime`, you will also need to cast it to `DateTime?`.
Alternatively, you can write `new DateTime?()`, which will create an empty (null) `Nullable<DateTime>` value.

Comment: A working example would make your answer complete, talking around nullables just makes it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Work with `SqlParameter` and not their value like so..

```
SqlParameter sp = col28Value == null ? new SqlParameter("@whatever", DBNull.Value) : new SqlParameter("@whatever", col28Value);
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily verbose, unnecessary, and exactly the opposite of the question.

Answer (score 0):

when you do this:

```
DateValue1 = col28Value == null ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(col28Value)
```

you may be doing :

```
DateValue1 = DbNull.Value;
```

which is not possible.  So replace DbNull.Value with null